# installing on new ubuntu 10.10 problems - diamondback has a zillion unmet dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I add the repositories and stuff with no problems, and when I try this:
sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-desktop-full

I get a bunch of error messages like the below sample:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-diamondback-desktop-full : Depends: ros-diamondback-ros-tutorials (= 0.2.4-s1299044686~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-geometry-tutorials (= 0.1.3-s1299044839~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.2-s1299034975~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
[many more ]

**And to answer my own question, it turns out I had some mysql stuff already installed that conflicted, and after I removed those packages, the full thing installed (well, is installing) okay**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9276/installing-on-new-ubuntu-10.10-problems---diamondback-has-a-zillion-unmet-dependencies/) by [Tonkabot](https://answers.ros.org/users/231/tonkabot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Coped from question edit to answer:

And to answer my own question, it turns out I had some mysql stuff already installed that conflicted, and after I removed those packages, the full thing installed (well, is installing) okay

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0